# Is it possible to put two Lambda expressions inside a single query?

Tags: c#, linq, syntax, lambda

I was wondering if there is an easy way to place two Lambda expressions in a single (Linq/Where) query?

For example, I currently call a method with something like the following:

```
string testing = "blablabla";
if(testing == "" || testing == null)
```

I have tried a few combinations such as:

```
testing.Where(x => x == ("") || x=> x == null);
```

But the above doesn't work. I know I can set up a method that returns a predicate/bool, but, at the moment, I am interested in Lambdas and was just wondering how to achieve this.

Do I need to chain multiple Where methods, or is there a way to achieve multiple Lambdas?

(p.s. I know about IsNullOrEmpty, this is just the first example I could think of!)

Comment: Does `String.IsNullOrEmpty` not work?

Comment: @Brad Christie and others - I know about IsNullOrEmpty - I have a slightly complicated method that would make no sense out of context and this was just the first example I could think of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always combine them to a single lambda.

```
testing.Where(x => x == null || x == ("")  );
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks... Unless someone else gives a better answer/huge explanation... I will mark this as answer when I can.

Comment: Yep, it makes the most sense to define a condition which each x must satisfy. Two separate lambda expressions is less logical

Comment: @Bala R - I am still learning about Lambdas... I certainly prefer this syntax to a whole separate method, but, do you happen to know speed / does it run quicker/slower than a separate method? ...

Comment: @WilliamHilsum I don't think there will be any difference in speed. Lambda expressions are [function delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and are syntactic sugar for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a general way to combine query conditions in arbitrary ways, you can use expression trees:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx